# How to list all the wikis from forks for a specific repository on Github?

Tags: github

I'm interested in an opensource project but it's documentation doesn't cover much of it's details.

The project was forked more that 500 times. One of the forks has an interesting wiki with rich information about the project.

I was thinking about listing the links for all the wikis for forks of that project.

I tried going through some forks manually but it takes time and some forks doesn't have a wiki in the first place !

So is there a way to list forks wikis links for a specific project on Github ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [GitHub API](https://developer.github.com/v3/) for that:

### 1. List all forks for a repo:

https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/forks/#list-forks

```
GET /repos/:owner/:repo/forks
```

You'll get back a list of forks looking like this *(example from the link, shortened for brevity)*:

```
[
  {
    "id": 1296269,
    "owner": {
      "login": "octocat",
      "id": 1,
      "avatar_url": "https://github.com/images/error/octocat_happy.gif",
      (...)
    },
    "name": "Hello-World",
    "full_name": "octocat/Hello-World",
    "description": "This your first repo!",
    "private": false,
    "fork": true,
    "url": "https://api.github.com/repos/octocat/Hello-World",
    "html_url": "https://github.com/octocat/Hello-World",
    "archive_url": "http://api.github.com/repos/octocat/Hello-World/{archive_format}{/ref}",
    "assignees_url": "http://api.github.com/repos/octocat/Hello-World/assignees{/user}",
    "blobs_url": "http://api.github.com/repos/octocat/Hello-World/git/blobs{/sha}",
    "branches_url": "http://api.github.com/repos/octocat/Hello-World/branches{/branch}",
    "clone_url": "https://github.com/octocat/Hello-World.git",
    (...)
    "tags_url": "http://api.github.com/repos/octocat/Hello-World/tags",
    "teams_url": "http://api.github.com/repos/octocat/Hello-World/teams",
    "trees_url": "http://api.github.com/repos/octocat/Hello-World/git/trees{/sha}",
    "homepage": "https://github.com",
    "language": null,
    "forks_count": 9,
    "stargazers_count": 80,
    "watchers_count": 80,
    "size": 108,
    "default_branch": "master",
    "open_issues_count": 0,
    "topics": [
      "octocat",
      "atom",
      "electron",
      "API"
    ],
    "has_issues": true,
    "has_wiki": true,
    "has_pages": false,
    "has_downloads": true,
    "pushed_at": "2011-01-26T19:06:43Z",
    "created_at": "2011-01-26T19:01:12Z",
    "updated_at": "2011-01-26T19:14:43Z",
    "permissions": {
      "admin": false,
      "push": false,
      "pull": true
    },
    "allow_rebase_merge": true,
    "allow_squash_merge": true,
    "allow_merge_commit": true,
    "subscribers_count": 42,
    "network_count": 0
  }
]
```

You can filter the repos which actually have a wiki by looking at the `has_wiki` property:

```
"has_wiki": true
```

---

### 2. Getting the wiki URL

Unfortunately, there are a lot of URLs with properties, but the wiki URL is not one of them.

So you need to construct it by yourself.
Fortunately, GitHub's wiki URLs are simple:

```
https://github.com/:owner/:repo/wiki
```

So with the example from above, it's just:

https://github.com/octocat/Hello-World -> https://github.com/octocat/Hello-World/wiki